# Database design changes for facebook connect with existing website users

Tags: php, mysql

I have already running website and would like to integrate facebook connect with it.

**My existing users table schema is** :

```
CREATE TABLE  `tbl_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(32)  NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(96)  NOT NULL ,
  `password` varchar(120)  NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `about_me` text,
  `image` varchar(120),
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What are the changes required in above db table design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following article:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-authenticate-your-users-with-facebook-connect/

Comment: Hi ben.. thanks.. i have gone through that article, but i want the db changes required in above users table.